# How to make an EditText wrap correctly in a Constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hello everyone I have a problem that I have been bashing my head against for 2 days now. It seems like such a simple issue but I just cant seem to solve it. Basically I am making a morse code translating app
When the user types into the EditText field it immediately translate the typed text into morse below.

**Problem:**
What I want is the EditTexts to expand to take up as much space as is needed but to wrap an become scrollable once they reache a certain height. The issue is virtually everything ive tried has resulted in one of the EditTexts pushing the other off screen or notwrapping its text at all.

**What Iv Got so far:**
I have a layout that does exactly what I want, And works the way I want. It just doesn't look the way I want. I am using Navigation components so the below view is inflated in the FragmentContainerView in the MainActivty. I am also setting the window behaviour  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/decoder_text_to_morse_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    tools:context=".Fragments.DecoderFragment"
   >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:padding="@dimen/four_dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:text="Text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/decode_changer_fab" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/eight_dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/include2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include1" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_morse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:text="Morse"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/decode_changer_fab" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:padding="@dimen/four_dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/decode_changer_fab" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Default layout] [image: Keyboard open] [image: Wrapping Long Text]

All I want is for the EditTexts to begin in a collapsed state, Expand to house their content and resize if the Keyboard is open. Using `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` doesnt work and causes the bottom EditText to push the top one off the screen. I realize `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` is deprecated and the recommended way is  `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` but the behaviour is the same with the bottom EditText pushing the top one off screen. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Really struggling to do a mundane thing -_-

Comment: I think what fixed it is using `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` as well as limiting the height of 1 of the EditTexts using `android:maxHeight="128dp"`. Now it seems like `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` with `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` is working. That said i'm sure sure I tried it this way and it still wasn't working. So Confused XD

Comment: Neither of these answers solved the problem. turned out it was an xml formatting issues. New question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66256281/a-question-for-anyone-experienced-with-android-and-xml-to-explain-a-mystery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me when I needed this, using max and min heights worked, after the max height, the edit text will become scrollable

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:maxHeight= //desired dimensions
      android:minHeight = //desired dimensions
       />
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried put:
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
inside your EditText tag ?
like :

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```