# A question for anyone experienced with Android and xml to explain a mystery

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am currently developing an app and I came across a bug where two `EditTexts` just would not wrap inside a constraint layout. I tried everything to fix the problem. placing `LinearLayouts` to try enforce height adding `CardViews`, adding chains etc, etc. I know the way to make an item wrap inside a `ConstraintLayout` is using `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` and setting the height to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, but even this wasn't working. Spent literal days trying to solve the problem, when yesterday I just lucked out and happened to move around my xml file and all of a sudden it started working.

**Working `fragment_layout_text_to_morse`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/decoder_text_to_morse_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    tools:context=".Fragments.DecoderFragment">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_morse"
        layout="@layout/layout_edit_text_morse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/decode_changer_fab" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/decode_changer_fab" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/eight_dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/include_morse"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/include_text" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_morse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:text="Morse"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/decode_changer_fab" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_text"
        layout="@layout/layout_edit_text_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**`layout_edit_text_morse`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/darkGreen">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_morse"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Morse"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**`layout_edit_text_text`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red"
       >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:maxHeight="128dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Results**

Everything works as expected. When the `EditTexts` are empty they occupy as little space as possible at the top of the screen. When the user types into them the red `EditText` grows to its limit and the green `EditText` occupies the rest of the space. They also both wrap their content correctly for if the keyboard is open

**Images**

[image: No text entered] [image: wrapping content with keyboard open] [image: wrapping without the keyboard open]

But this is where thing start to get strange. Simply but swapping the position of the top and bottom include statements in the xml the layout breaks

**Broken `fragment_layout_text_to_morse`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/decoder_text_to_morse_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    tools:context=".Fragments.DecoderFragment">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_text"
        layout="@layout/layout_edit_text_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/decode_changer_fab" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/eight_dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/include_morse"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/include_text" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_morse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:text="Morse"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/decode_changer_fab"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/decode_changer_fab" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_morse"
        layout="@layout/layout_edit_text_morse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/decode_changer_fab" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now the Green `EditText` pushes the red one and the buttons off screen

[image: No longer wrapping correctly]

My question is what's the difference in terms of the xml? I understand that xml is parsed from top to bottom, But how is moving the include statements making such a difference? Sure in a `LinearLayout` I could understand but why is `ConstraintLayout` behaving this way? Doesn't it consume the entire xml and then calculate the constraints? My worry is, like I said earlier I just lucked out to solve this as I would never format my code this way, having the top most view at the bottom of the xml let alone the head of a chain being below the tail. Anyone that can explain why this is happening will be my hero :)

PS: I am using navigation components in the project so the `fragment_layout_text_to_morse` is inflated into the `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` of the `MainActivity`. I am also setting the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` Not sure if any of this is pertinent but hey extra info :)

Comment: I am just guessing here but `match_parent` is a big no-no with _ConstraintLayout_ and you have a few. (There is a reference to this in the documentation that, if I remember, says something about being unpredictable.) Change `match_parent` to `0dp` and control the width/height with constraints to see if that fixes it. There really should be a lint check for this.

Comment: @Cheticamp Yeah confirmed it. Changed all the `match_parent` to `0dp` and it made no difference. The Bottom `EditText` still pushes the top off screen.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes about because `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` is specified for both of the include files. Only the first `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` is honored and the second is not.

Here is a simplified layout to demonstrate the problem:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/decoder_text_to_morse_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/include_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:hint="Text"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/include_morse"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/include_morse"
        layout="@layout/layout_edit_text_morse"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkGreen"
        android:hint="Morse"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include_text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Since only the first view with `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` is honored, then the order will matter. You can try various combinations of this flag in the above layout to see what I mean. (ConstraintLayout version 2.0.4 is used.)

I would expect both flags to be honored instead of just one, but this is one of those cases where it is difficult to discern whether it is a defect or just a limitation.

Setting `app:layout_constrainedHeight="false"` for both views and relying on the vertical chain to do its job works a little better, but the layout slides a little beneath the status and navigation bars on the emulator.

Comment: Yeah but when the xml is switched around it seems to be honouring both `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"`? It seems to be constraining both. Unless it ignores one of the `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` when you set a max height? I did try to just let the chain do its thing but it actually goes a long way under the system bars. multiple lines if the text is long. What's even weirder is if you give it a margin away from the system bars it disappears under the margins. The actual `ConstraintLayout` itself isn't reporting its height correctly

Comment: @AlexanderRobinson In my example, only the first constrained_height=true is honored and the other is not. I don't see any combination that results in the honoring of both. Regardless, something is not right here. If you can frame the issue, you may want to consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: Yeah I think its a bug. The behavior seems pretty strange. Will try to get a clear idea of what causes the issues over next week.